# StackExchange.Redis with multiple client names

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

We have a need to use multiple client names with StackExchange.Redis, which as far as I can tell means multiple connection strings and multiple (static) instances of `ConnectionMultiplexer`.

My current thinking is to create a static wrapper class and use a private dictionary keyed by client name (or the whole connection string) to store the multiplexer instances, and expose a single `GetDatabase(name)` method which looks up the multiplexer (or locks and creates it) and returns the result of the `GetDatabase()` call on the instance to the caller.

This was the first thing I thought of, but I wouldn't be surprised if there were a better way to handle this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same situation in the past in which I need to change the connection dynamically based on the configuration. To overcome that I have created static `Helper` class which takes endpoint IP address as input and returns connection as result.

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper class for connection with Redis Server.
/// </summary>
public static class Helper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Configuration option to connect with Redis.
    /// </summary>
    private static Lazy<ConfigurationOptions> configOptions(string ipAddress)
    {
        var configOptions = new ConfigurationOptions();
        configOptions.EndPoints.Add(ipAddress);
        /*
        ...Other Configurations...
        */
        return new Lazy<ConfigurationOptions>(() => configOptions);
    }

    private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection(string ipAddress)
    {
        return new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configOptions(ipAddress).Value));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Connection property to connect Redis.
    /// </summary>
    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection(string ipAddress)
    {
        return lazyConnection(ipAddress).Value;
    }
}
```

How to use this:

```
var database = Helper.Connection("Your IP address").GetDatabase(0);
```

This is the simple workaround, of course, you can modify it as per your need and make it more configurable. The idea here is to make Redis connection dynamic so that we can perform other operation based on that, like setting and getting keys and values.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I'm doing, thanks for the code sample.